# Browsable intent filter does not open my application

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, intentfilter

I am trying to use intent filter to open URLs in my application (as opening http://market.android.com/ opens the Android Market).

According to docs I've found, with this code, opening http://seenthis.net/people/progval in the browser should open my application:

```
    <activity android:name=".ShowUserActivity" android:permission="android.permission.INTERNET">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category
                android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category
                android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                android:scheme="http"
                android:host="seenthis.net"
                android:pathPattern="/people/.*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

But it does not.

Here is the activity:

```
public class ShowUserActivity extends ListActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("SeenDroid", "called");
        String url = getIntent().getDataString();
        if (url != null) {
            Log.d("SeenDroid", url);
        }
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

But nothing is logged to the logcat.

Regards,
ProgVal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove `android:permission="android.permission.INTERNET"` from your `activity` declaration.